# Adding CIFilter to CALayer under Mavericks?

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-animation, calayer, cifilter

so this is the standard way of adding filter to a layer:

```
NSView *view = self.window.contentView;
view.wantsLayer = YES;
CATextLayer *textLayer = [CATextLayer layer];
textLayer.frame = CGRectMake(10.0, 10.0, 200.0, 100.0);
textLayer.string = @"foo";
textLayer.foregroundColor = [[NSColor redColor] CGColor];

// Add filter
CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIGaussianBlur" keysAndValues:@"inputRadius", @5.0, nil];
textLayer.filters = @[filter];

// Attach layer
[view.layer addSublayer:textLayer];
```

However, it crashes my application on OS X Mavericks. Used to work on 10.8.

```
2013-10-23 13:09:20.767 Serus[3608:303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CAInvalidCIFilter', reason: 'CI filters are not supported by this layer tree: {CIGaussianBlur {
    inputImage = "<null>";
    inputRadius = 10;
}}.'
```

**CI filters are not supported by this layer tree**

Anybody ever seen this? What may I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Figured it out, Apple decided to change this and require a new flag for no reason

```
progressIndicator.layerUsesCoreImageFilters = YES;
```

Comment: Thanks! I had the same issue with setCompositingFilter: and this fixes it.

Comment: It's not for no reason, it's because by default CALayers are rendered out of process now to allow the OS to share resources better. Could certainly be documented better - may I suggest a radar :) /cc @uliwitness

Comment: from the docs for this method... If you assign Core Image filters to your view using the setBackgroundFilters:, setCompositingFilter:, or setContentFilters: methods, you do not need to call this method explicitly. Those methods automatically let AppKit know that it needs to render the layer hierarchy in-process.

Comment: It should be noted that this is a property set on the `NSView`, _not the layer_.. And for anyone interested... it is declared in the `AppKit.h` header.

Comment: got stung by this one as well!